wp_logout function not executed
Context: a custom plugin
My goal: i need to redirect user to another site after a logout
I wrote these
error_log("test of error logging");

add_action('wp_logout', function () {
  error_log("do_action wp_logout_called");
});

add_action('wp_logout', function()
  {
    wp_redirect('https://www.google.it');
    exit();
  };

In the error_log i can see test of error logging, so plugin is loaded and error logging works
But

I never see do_action wp_logout_called, never logged at all
The redirect is not working (the user returns to wordpress, no error, no redirect)

What am I doing wrong?
Edit 1 - More trial
I tried a manual logut using
http://www.domain.ext/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it&_wpnonce=a7b9f2e2b0

Esit: logout works, but i'm redirected to home page.

The second add_action does not have a valid second parameter, I would expect that code to produce a PHP syntax error, have you modified it for the question to hide things?

Thanks for pointing the error. Anyway was only a copy/paste error.

If I run the above code directly in a plugin file, it seems to error log which leads me to believe there's a 3rd party code preventing it. I tested this through admin page log out, not any specific log out form/button. I'd try to isolate the code, maybe it has to do when/how the action is being added. Disabling themes and plugins to help narrow down the issue as well.

I also tested the code on a local sandbox WP and it worked as expected. As Howdy_McGee commented this is probably a conflict with 3rd party code.
If disabling theme and plugins is not an option, you can try changing the priority of the actions - i.e. the third parameter to add_action().
By default priority is 10, but if you give it a lower number it will be executed earlier - possibly before 3rd party actions.
